# how to get the num of records from a table?

Tags: abap, opensql

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords FROM tableX;` how do I convert this to sap ABAP

Comment: ...without bothering to even use Google to search for an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For database tables you can do `SELECT COUNT`like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( * )
    INTO numberOfRecords
    FROM tableX.
```

To get the line count of an internal table you need the `DESCRIBE` statement:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE tableX LINES numberOfRecords.
```

Comment: Don't you have to add `SINGLE` to use this `SELECT` without `ENDSELECT`?

Comment: It works both with and without `SINGLE` on our system. The F1 help doesn't show `SINGLE` for aggregate functions

Answer (score 1):

For internal tables you can use this build in function as well:

```
numberOfRecords = lines( tableX)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and a colleague gave me to following.
I needed the counts of entries in a db table for a key, and didn'enter code heret want to do a select count(*) in a loop.
So, we created a sorted table with the unique key, did a select... endselect into that table with the condition BEFORE the loop, and in the loop simply read this new sorted table:

```
types:
            begin of ts_tab
                        f1 type 1
                        f2 type 2
                        f3 type i
            end of ts_tab
            tt_tab type sorted table of ts_tab
            with unigue key f1 f2
 
select f1 f2 into coorresponding fields of ls_tab
            read table lt_tab assigning <ls_tab>
                        with table key f1 = f1 etc.
            if sy-subrc = 0.
                        add 1 to <ls_tab>-f3
            else.
                        ls_tab-f3 = 1.
                        insert ls_tab into lt_tab.
            endif.
endselect 
loop etc.

   read lt_tab into ls_tab with key f1 = f1 f2 = f2.
   if sy-subrc eq 0.
      my_count = ls_tabl-f3.
   endif

endloop
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use ABAP Statement:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE itab[] lines lv_no.
```

Answer (score -2):

1) If you just want the count of the records in database table, use the following syntax.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) INTO RecordCount FROM tableX.
```

2) But, if you need the records for processing, as well as the count then use following.

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE itab FROM tableX.
DESCRIBE TABLE itab[] lines RecordCount.
```

Comment: There is a difference in the syntax of the Case 2.

Comment: Hardly any. I believe the question was about SQL table, not the internal tables. If it was about internal tables then `lines( )` is more suitable.

Comment: The difference i am pointing to is in this line. SELECT * INTO TABLE itab FROM tableX. Anyway, i later realized it was an old post. So not much use in arguing among us.